# Access anonymous, public samba share without prompt

Tags: 17.10, filemanager

I have two public, anonymously accessible samba shares [bookmarked in File manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWCf8.png) in 17.10.

Every time I mount (click) them I am [prompted to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk0Zc.png), but as an anonymous user, there is nothing to submit. Is there a way to auto accept this connection prompt? Is this based on the samba client or File manager or something else?